# how to handle multiple events on forms in c#

Tags: c#

in my current project ,i have a form which contains 2 command buttons named COPY and Cancel
if i click COPY button it is copying 3000 files from source directory to a destination directory ,at the same time if click the Cancel Button , it should cancel the copy and exit the form. is there any way to do so?

i applied the solution but got errors. i have the following code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication8
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private volatile bool _continue = false;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _continue = true;
            System.Threading.ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(print_number);
            System.Threading.Thread t = new Thread(ts);
            t.Start();
        }
        private void print_number()
        {
            for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++)
            {
                textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(i);
                if (_continue == false)
                {
                    return;
                }

                //Thread.Sleep(2000);
            }
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _continue = false;
            Close();
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: The C# FAQ answers this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2010/07/19/parallel-programming-task-cancellation.aspx (There are many ways to do this; that link demonstrates one valid way.)

Comment: How are you performing the task of copying the files from source to destination?

Comment: You would only be able to cancel the copy operation if the copy operation were being performed on a worker thread, otherwise the UI thread wouldn't be able to respond to the click on the Cancel button because the UI thread would be busy performing the copy operation.

Comment: i am using FILE.copy() method in System.IO;

Comment: Yes there is a way to do this.  Do some research, try some code, and come back when you get stuck.  Look at threading.

Comment: @Manas `File.Copy` should be the method used.  But really we need to know how you are performing the work, are you offloading the work to some worker from the UI thread?  If not then that should be your first task before you can even attempt cancellation.  Posting the code in question will help the community help you.

Comment: my answer should work...

Comment: Can anyone help me in the following issues where i am getting errors while using the text box in threading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Example:

```
private volatile bool _continue = false;

private void CopyClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   _continue = true;
   System.Threading.ThreadStart ts = new ThreadStart(CopyFiles);
   System.Threading.Thread t = new Thread(ts);
   t.Start();
}

private void CopyFiles(){
   List<String> list = GetFileNames();
   foreach( String f in list )
   {
      if ( _continue == false )
      {
        return;
      }
      CopyFile(s);  //examples...
   }

}
private void CancelClicked(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _continue = false;
    Close();
}
```

Comment: `_continue` should really be marked with the [`volatile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7.aspx) keyword